# Linking external DKM (.o file) with the DKM project in WindRiver workbench 4.1

Tags: object, linker, elf, vxworks

I want to link my external .o file (source code not available) with the VxSim based image project in Workbench. I am able to load this .o file as a module and run it. However, since it is an external file, library calls like "printf" doesn't work.

Hence, I want to link it to partialImage.o so that it gets the definition of the library (like stdio) functions.

How can I achieve this?

I am expecting that the external .o file is linked to partialImage.o

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

In project settings, we can add the external module (.o) file in EXTERN_MODULES variable.